# IntelliJ IDEA Java How to make Run configurations automatically select Main Class

Tags: java, intellij-idea

My friend and I both have IntelliJ and just want to run plain old java. Every time I make a new java class, I can automatically run it. The configurations just work.

When my friend wants to run it, he has to go to edit configurations and type in the class name. We went through the exact same setup. How do we make it automatically the main function in the class?

Friend's

[image]
[image]

MINE Macbook Pro

[image: Thing]

Comment: maybe your friend have more than one class with main method so he must select which one to run?

Comment: Can you highlight the differences between your settings and your friend settings?

Comment: @firegloves Well we both have 1 module and multiple classes all with the main method. For mine, if I run from my class two.java then it runs two's main, but if I run three.java it runs three's main. If friend Nihar runs two.java after making the configuration and decides to run three.java, he has to go to edit configurations and change the main class method.

Comment: We are running identical JDK versions. Both added a custom run configuration for an Application. Our project structure looks identical (project created Empty). I can't think of any differences. If someone would like me to post more info I can. Somehow a default setting of mine must have changed

Comment: Make sure your friend directory that contains the java code is marked as source. To do that right click on directory > `Mark Directory As` > `Sources Root`

Comment: I think you posted the same image twice. You could try exporting your settings and sharing it with your friend https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/exporting-and-importing-settings.html that might solve the problem for him. If that is not the case try going to File -> project structure and check for differences in there.

Comment: @Dontas You're totally right, I posted mine twice. I didn't realize because the firewall blocks images from imgur. I fixed it. As for exporting settings, I'm going to try that today when I see him. Also we tried coletrain's situation and nothing noticeable happened.

Answer (score 2):

When you're in a java file that contains a `public static final void main(String[] arg)` method you can press `Ctrl+Shift+F10` to make and run a temporary run configuration for the current class. This can save a bit of time when setting up the configurations.

Alternatively you can try to share the `.idea` directory with him, as it contains all of the project's settings. I'm not sure what other options will be shared though.

Comment: @slashdottir It shows the shortcut if you right-click in the file, I think for mac it's going to be `Ctrl + Fn + Shift + F10`.

Answer (score 1):

it's easy, Your friend must do this and this setting is changed in the "Default Project Structure..." dialog. Navigate to "File" -> "Other Settings" -> "Default Project Structure...".

[image: Select Default Project Structure]

Next, modify the "Project language level" setting to your desired language level.

[image: Setting the project language level]

IntelliJ IDEA 12 had this setting in "Template Project Structure..." instead of "Default Project Structure..."

Answer (score 0):

Creating files in the src(source folder) where the jvm expects to find the java classes instead of creating them in the project root folder helped solve the problem for me.